# RangeAccrualFloaterCoupon not visible Quantlib Swig

Tags: quantlib

I was wondering why `RangeAccrualFloatersCoupon` is not accessible through SWIG QuantLib. I am currently using QuantLib python. Can anyone help ?
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all of QuantLib is exported through SWIG—the process is only semi automated.

You can [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG) to request it to be exported.

Comment: Thanks Luigi for your answer. I just opened an issue as advised.